# Seeing what is substituted for a variable in a For loop

Tags: r

When I write `for` loops, it's usually using a generic variable, like:

```
barcodes = data.frame(some data with 20 rows and 6 columns)

for (i in barcodes[1:8,]){
barcode <- (i["P7_Barcode"])  
print(barcode)
}
```

In this particular example, I'm trying to get the value for the P7_Barcode column for the `ith` row. It's not working out for me. It would be great to know what R is filling in for `i`.  Is there a way to find out the actual argument that is being substituted for `i`? That would help me debug much more easily.

Comment: Hi. I tried to provide a better example. I want to see not the actual value of i, but what the argument is. So, for example, here, I'm assuming that `i` is some row of the data.frame `barcodes`, say barcodes[1,]. So that is what I am assuming is being substituted for `i` at the very first iteration of the loop. But is there a way to actual see that?

Comment: Your `for` sequence is incorrect: `for(i in 1:nrow(barcodes)) { barcode <- barcode[i, "P7_Barcode"]; print(barcode) }`

Comment: Thank you! That solves this particular problem. But to the more general question of finding out what is being substituted for `i` (in some future case), is there a way to get that?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a few options:

1. Add either a `cat(i, \n)` or a `print(i)` to the loop.
2. If you're using RStudio or Visual Studio, set a breakpoint in the loop.
3. Add `browser()` into your loop to allow for interactive debugging (effectively the same as 2, but not reliant on using an IDE).